# Authentication Window Alert is working in IE11 but not working in Chrome v60

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my scenario, when I launch a URL, an authentication alert window opens up and I need to enter Username and Password from excel and on clicking on 'Log In' it'll show me the web homepage. I've implemented this using the below code snippet and it's working perfectly in IE11. But when I'm trying to run the same code in Chrome v60, it's not working. It's showing the authentication alert window but not performing any action on it. Screenshot attached. Can anyone suggest please.

Selenium WD version - 3.4.0

**Code:**

```
public static void loadApplicationURL(WebDriver driver) throws Exception 
    {
        String SSPathl = null;
        String URL = Generic_Functions.GetParameterFromInputSheet("URL");
        try
        {
            driver.get(URL);
            Thread.sleep(6000); 
            LoginApplication.isAlertPresent(driver);
}
}
public static boolean isAlertPresent(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            driver.switchTo().alert();
            UserAndPassword UP = new UserAndPassword(UserName,Password);
            driver.switchTo().alert().authenticateUsing(UP);
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            return true;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
}
}
```

For test browsers, have created a separate class. Find below the snippet used for IE and Chrome browsers.

**For Chrome**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\Resources\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver()
```

**In case of IE,**

```
[System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",".\\Resources\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
            ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);][1]
```

Comment: Seems the consensus is to use Robot Framework or AutoIT.

Comment: Or you can directly type the user:pass in the url.  "http://UserName:Password@yoururl.com"